# Avoid This collection already contains an address with scheme http

Tags: wcf, http, iis, schema, hosting

I have this issue:

I have WebSite with asp.net pages.

`http://desiis:90/WebSite1`

In this webSite, I have a Service WCF (service1.svc).

`http://desiis:90/WebSite1/services/Service1.svc`

When I call to the service, I get this error:

`This collection already contains an address with scheme http`

In my localhost all is OK.

any solution, please ??

note: aspx page and WCF service is in the same web application is required

My current scenario is that the ASPX web page use forms authentication and it will call a WCF service, and you want to let the forms authenticated identity be transfered to WCF service.

1) if aspx page and WCF service is in the same web application, you can turn on AspNetCompatiblity mode for WCF so that the HttpContext will be available to WCF service operation code.

thanks in advance, greetings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's likely you're hosting this inside of IIS, and your host has multiple addresses configured.

[This](http://www.robzelt.com/blog/2007/01/24/WCF+This+Collection+Already+Contains+An+Address+With+Scheme+Http.aspx) is what I did to solve this problem.

Comment: Link rot... What exactly did you do?